# Common eigenvectors implies simultaneously block diagonalizations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A,B$ are symmetric matrices of the same size. If $A,B$ have a common eigenvectors, can we block diagonalize them at the same time?

More specifically, suppose $A$ and $B$ have one common eigenvector $v$ , and  $Av = \lambda v$ and $Bv =\mu v$. We say $A$ and $B$ are block diagonalized at the same time if there is a orthogonal matrix $V$  such that 
$$V^t A V=\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and} \quad V^tBV=\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 \\ 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix}.$$

If $A$ and $B$ have more that one common eigenvectors, it  can be defined in  a similar way as above.

Can we find such an orthogonal matrix $V$?

Comment: How many common eigenvectors do they share? Just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $v \neq 0$ is a common eigenvector. Thus, $\mathrm{span}(v)$ is stable by $A$ and $B$. By orthogonality, $\mathrm{span}(v)^{\perp}$ is also stable by $A$ and $B$. Take $(e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ a basis of $\mathrm{span}(v)^{\perp}$. Then $(v,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ is a basis of the ambiant space, and in this basis, the matrices of $A$ and $B$ are of the wanted form.

Comment: But it won't be block diagonal right? Namely, with this method we can only guarantee that $V^T A V$ is of form
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & * \\ 0 & *\end{bmatrix}$$
but not
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & *\end{bmatrix}$$
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it would be. If $\mathrm{span}(v)^{\perp} = \mathrm{span}(e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ is stable by $A$, this means that for any $x \in \mathrm{span}(e_2,\ldots,e_n)$, $Ax \in \mathrm{span}(e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ too. So it has a zero coordinate on $\mathrm{span}(v)$.